# How to make an app which simply opens a browser when user taps on launch icon on iOS?

Tags: ios

I made such an app on Android. It was easy. I just made the main activity transparent and launched browser intent after it starts. Is there any way on iOS to make main ViewController fully transparent and just call openURL?
Or are there any other solutions?

Comment: You can use SFSafariViewController, WKWebview, UIWebView (depending on iOS version). Not sure I understand why would you make the VC transparent if you are going to present a new app on top of it.

Comment: I don't get it, how is this different than the user launching Safari? Or are you trying to launch the browser with a certain URL? In that case it's already built in to iOS, go to any webpage, press square with up arrow, the select "Add to Home Screen".

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use a UIWebView (`WKWebView`). However, Apple isn't likely to approve such an app. From the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality):

> 4.2 Minimum Functionality
>
> Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it
>   beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful,
>   unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store. If your App
>   doesn't provide some sort of lasting entertainment value, or is just
>   plain creepy, it may not be accepted. Apps that are simply a song or
>   movie should be submitted to the iTunes Store. Apps that are simply a
>   book or game guide should be submitted to the iBooks Store.